# How to put text below some text in an equation

Tags: equations

[image]

Please refer the attached image. I want to write `\omega \in \mathbb{R}` below `sup` as shown in the equation in the image. How should I do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For what you want:

```
Er=\sup_{\omega\in\mathbb{R}}||G(j\omega)-R(j\omega)||_\infty
```

[image]

If you want to put arbitrary text (or anything) below some other text (or anything you want) *generally* you can use `\underset{}{}` and `\mathop{}` like this

```
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\underset{Under}{Normal}
```

or

```
\mathop{Normal}_{Under}
```

[image]

Comment: Combining `\underset` and `\mathop` is a little redundant: either `\underset{Under}{Normal}` or `\mathop{Normal}_{Under}` would work, but for `\lim`-style operators `\operatorname*{Normal}` is advisable (or you could put `\DeclareMathOperator*{\Normal}{Normal}` in the preamble and then use `\Normal`). Note that `\underset`, `\operatorname` and `\DeclareMathOperator` all require `amsmath`.

Comment: (I just posted the answer because I use it :)))

Comment: No problem. Your answer is good, but you should remove `\mathop` in the second code block (it effectively does nothing) and you might want to mention that you need to load `amsmath` to use `\underset`.

Comment: @Circumscribe Actually I got it from `Toogle TeX` option of MathType one year ago when I am just a newbie to LaTeX. I always load `amsmath` package in all of my files, so I don't see any problem :) Thank you for give me more very useful knowledge!

Comment: Yeah, you'll probably always want to load `amsmath` if you're typesetting anything that that involves equations. While we're at it, it is better to use `\|` instead of `||` (because it is a single character), and better still to use `\lVert` and `\rVert` (also from `amsmath`) because these have better spacing.