# How to have subscript below max in cases environment

Tags: math-mode

Whit the following code the max subscript is displayed on the right of max, while I want it to be below. Removing the cases fixes the issue, but still I need it. How can I fix that ?

```
   \begin{equation}
      f(i)=\begin{cases}
        0, & \text{if $S_{i}$ is empty}.\\
        \max_{t_k \in S_{i}}\{f(k) + 42\}, & \text{otherwise}.
      \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
```

Comment: You could use `\max\limits_{...}` or the `dcases` environment from `mathtools`.

Comment: `\max\limits_{...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `\max\limits_{}` works well! However, if you want a general answer, read [this answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/460250/156344) (which is also mine):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    f(i)=\begin{cases}
        0, & \text{if $S_{i}$ is empty}.\\
        \underset{t_k \in S_{i}}{\max}\{f(k) + 42\}, & \text{otherwise}.
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, `\underset` is the wrong tool for this.