# Is there a way to create logical or as a sum-class symbol?

Tags: equations, formatting, symbols

Example:

```
\begin{equation}
    \lor_{j=1}^n
\end{equation}
```

shows up like

[image: or sum]

and

```
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{j=1}^n
\end{equation}
```

shows up like

[image: sum sum]

Is there a way to make the `\lor` look like the `\sum` symbol with its limits?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460248/how-to-put-text-below-some-text-in-an-equation).

Comment: Are you looking for `\bigvee`? `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\bigvee_{j=1}^{n}\]
\end{document}`

Comment: @marmot \bigvee and \bigwedge are exactly what I have been looking for! Please create an answer so I can accept it.